# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'fldProjectId'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I know this question has been answered multpiple times on this site but none of the solutions works for me.I am sure it has to do with the way the project is created.So There is a database  created with tables ,then i followed this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx  guide on how to crate a project with my database.Next in the same project/solution i created  an upload function mostly followed instructions from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc/ but had to change some of the structure to get the functionality i need.Now for the last step which i thought would be  the easiest one, i want to have both views into the same view,so i used partial view for the database view to be outputted into the uploadfunction view, all input fields of  the partial view work fine but the dropdownlist which is  generated from the databse returns that error.
I started this project on the latest version of VS2017 .
I started using asp.net, c# and VS this week so i reliase i might have some stupid mistake   i dont understand thats why i am posting this thanks in advance.

This the controller for tblReleaseNotesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class tblReleaseNotesController : Controller
    {
        private SoftwareCatalogDBEntities2 db = new SoftwareCatalogDBEntities2();



        public ActionResult _View()
        {
            ViewData["fldProjectId"] = new SelectList(db.tblProjects, "fldId", "fldName");
            //ViewBag.fldProjectId = new SelectList(db.tblProjects, "fldId", "fldName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: tblReleaseNotes/
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult _View([Bind(Include = "fldId,fldDate,fldVersion,fldNotes,fldFaults,fldProjectId")] tblReleaseNote tblReleaseNote)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tblReleaseNotes.Add(tblReleaseNote);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.fldProjectId = new SelectList(db.tblProjects, "fldId", "fldName", tblReleaseNote.fldProjectId);
            return View(tblReleaseNote);
        }
   }
}
```

This is the Model tblReleaseNote.cs

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblReleaseNote
    {
        public int fldId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime fldDate { get; set; }
        public string fldVersion { get; set; }
        public string fldNotes { get; set; }
        public string fldFaults { get; set; }
        public int fldProjectId { get; set; }

        public virtual tblProject tblProject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

"UploadFiles.chtml"
The View in which i want to display the Create View with its partial view .

```
@model UploadMultipleFilesInMVC.Models.FileModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Software Catalogue";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div><br /><br /><br />
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Partial("../tblReleaseNotes/_View", Model) 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-success">
                @ViewBag.UploadStatus
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

UploadFiles Model

```
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace UploadMultipleFilesInMVC.Models
{
    public class FileModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file.")]
        [Display(Name = "Browse File")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }

    }
}
```

UploadFiles Controller

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;


namespace UploadMultipleFilesInMVC.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home  
        public ActionResult UploadFiles()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            //Ensure model state is valid  
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {   //iterating through multiple file collection   
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    //Checking file is available to save.  
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var relDirPath = "~/UploadedFiles/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(InputFileName);
                        var ServerSavePath = Server.MapPath(relDirPath);
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(ServerSavePath);
                        //Save file to server folder  
                        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(ServerSavePath, InputFileName));
                        //assigning file uploaded status to ViewBag for showing message to user.  
                        ViewBag.UploadStatus = files.Count().ToString() + " files uploaded successfully.";
                    }

                }
            }
            return View();            
        }

    }
}
```

This is the partial view which is the same as its parent view

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.tblReleaseNote

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">


        <h4>tblReleaseNote</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fldDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fldDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fldDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fldVersion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fldVersion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fldVersion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fldNotes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fldNotes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fldNotes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fldFaults, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fldFaults, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fldFaults, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fldProjectId, "fldProjectId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("fldProjectId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fldProjectId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thx for marking it as duplicate before reading the whole question cause as i have mentioned none of the answers on stackoverflow or the ones i found elsewere worked for me.

Comment: The error means that the value of `fldProjectId` is `null` - in your `UploadFiles` methods you have not returned a model to the view or set the value of `fldProjectId` to a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. And note that `@Html.Partial()` does not call a server method - it just renders the html in that view. To call the `_View()` method which does set a `ViewData["fldProjectId"]` value, then you need `@Html.Action()`